# linux and shared libraries and different g++ compilers

Tags: c++, linux

What is the story regarding having a process on Linux, which dlopen() multiple shared libraries and the executable and/or the shared libraries compiled with different C++ compilers (e.g. provided by customers or 3rd parties).

Am I going right in the following assumptions:

1. there is only a single namespace for symbols in a linux process. Symbols are found and resolved only by symbol name. The source of the symbol is random in the presence of an unknown executable (customer supplied) or customer supplied shared libraries.
2. there is no way to make certain, that STL/boost symbols are being resolved from the correct source, as they are always weak and thus might be overwritten.

What are the implications of using multiple copies of (different) libc++ inside the same process (some of them static)?

I don't expect seperate libraries to be able to talk to each other via a C++ interface but only via a C interface. What I would like is, that one can load SharedLibraries from different vendors into a single process and they do not screw up each other.

I know that this has worked in Windows for decades

Comment: Different vendors C++ code won't ever cooperate. Details: https://yosefk.com/c++fqa/mixing.html

Comment: @Lorinczy Zsigmond What do you mean cooperate? I don't expect it to be able to talk to each other via a C++ interface but only via a C interface. What I expect is, that one can load SharedLibraries from different vendors into a single process and they do not screw up each other. (This btw is working on Windows since decades)

Comment: @FrankPuck mentioning that in your question would have been a very good idea.  Missing it out, makes your question very misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Your comment completely changes your question:

> I don't expect it to be able to talk to each other via a C++ interface but only via a C interface. What I expect is, that one can load SharedLibraries from different vendors into a single process and they do not screw up each other. (This btw is working on Windows since decades)

This element of behaviour is largely system indipendant.  The [Windows PE format](https://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_peering_inside_pe.htm) and Linux [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) are similar enough in design that they don't add any additional constraints or capabilities on this topic.  So if your technique was going to work in Windows then it should also do so in Linux, just replacing `.dll` files for `.so` files.

Linux has more standardisation around [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) than Windows, so if anything you should find that Linux make's this simpler.

---

### Origional Answer

Question:

> *there is only a single namespace for symbols in a Linux process?*

That's correct; there's no such thing as namespaces in Linux's loader.

As you may know, C and C++ are very different languages.  C++ has namespaces C does not.  When libraries are loaded (in both Linux, Unix and also Windows) there is no concept of namespace.

C++ compilers use [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) to ensure that names isolated by namespaces in your code, do not compiled when placed as symbols in the shared object. C compilers don't do this and don't need to do it because there are no namespaces.

---

Question:

> *Symbols are found and resolved only by symbol name. The source of the symbol is random in the presence of an unknown executable (customer supplied) or customer supplied shared libraries.*

Let's replace the word "random" for unpredictable.  That's also correct.  [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C++):

> The C++ language does not define a standard decoration scheme, so each compiler uses its own. C++ also has complex language features, such as classes, templates, namespaces, and operator overloading, that alter the meaning of specific symbols based on context or usage. Meta-data about these features can be disambiguated by mangling (decorating) the name of a symbol. Because the name-mangling systems for such features are not standardized across compilers, few linkers can link object code that was produced by different compilers.

---

Question:

> What is the story regarding having a process on LINUX, which dlopen() multiple shared libraries and the executable and/or the shared libraries compiled with different C++ compilers (e.g. provided by customers or 3rd parties).

You can off course [dlopen()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) a shared object, but [dlsym()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) would be tricky to use because of name mangling.  You'd have to inspect the shared object manually to determine the precise symbol name.

---

> What are the implications of using multiple copies of (different) libc++ inside the same process (some of them static)?

If you got that far, then I'd be concerned about memory management first of all.  libc++ is responsible for implementing `new` and `delete` and converting these  into memory requests from the OS.  If they behave anything [like GNU's malloc() and free()](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Freeing-after-Malloc.html#:%7E:text=The%20free%20function%20deallocates%20the%20block%20of%20memory%20pointed%20at%20by%20ptr%20.&text=Occasionally%2C%20free%20can%20actually%20return,malloc%20to%20reuse%20the%20space.), they might manage their own pool of memory.  It'd be hard to prectict what would happen if you called `delete` on an object that was created by a different libc++.

Comment: A side note: dlsym would be tricky provided the symbols have standard C++ linkage. A good practice is to use C linkage on external (exported) interface functions (or even provide a complete C wrapper for the library)

Comment: @alagner agreed.  If you have control over the compiled libraries, then don't use a C++ interface use a C interface.  But that's the upshot of this answer. ;-)

Comment: my question had nothing to do with C++ namespaces?!?!

Comment: @FrankPuck You mentioned namespaces WRT symbols, but there's no concept of namespaces for Linux symbols.  However the point about C++ namespaces is how they're handled with name mangling.  The fact name mangling is used and the fact different compilers do it differently means that symbols generated from C++ names won't match between compilers.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that parts of this randomness can be avoided by loading the shared libraries using the following flags passed to dlopen():

- RTLD_LOCAL
- RTLD_DEEPBIND